# RuntimeException: Error in evaluationEvaluation: status: 13 value: {message=Invalid or unexpected token}

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-play, firebase-test-lab

when i uploaded to google play console, and review finished. apk rejected by showing this error. how to solve this problem, anyone have a solution?

FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-9
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in evaluationEvaluation: status: 13 value: {message=Invalid or unexpected token} hasMessage: true message: Invalid or unexpected token
at androidx.test.espresso.web.sugar.Web$WebInteraction$ExceptionPropagator.(Web.java:2)
at androidx.test.espresso.web.sugar.Web$WebInteraction.doEval(Web.java:10)
at androidx.test.espresso.web.sugar.Web$WebInteraction.perform(Web.java:1)
at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.hybrid.HybridInteractionController.swipe(HybridInteractionController.java:15)
at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:36)
at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.ActionExecutor.performAction(ActionExecutor.java:4)
at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.RemotePlatform.handlePerformAction(RemotePlatform.java:22)
at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.RemotePlatform.messageLoop(RemotePlatform.java:46)
at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.RemotePlatform.lambda$startCrawlAndWaitUntilFinished$0$androidx-test-tools-crawler-platform-RemotePlatform(RemotePlatform.java:1)
at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.RemotePlatform$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:6)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in evaluationEvaluation: status: ١٣ value: {message=Invalid or unexpected token} hasMessage: true message: Invalid or unexpected token
at androidx.test.espresso.web.model.SimpleAtom.handleBadEvaluation(SimpleAtom.java:1)
at androidx.test.espresso.web.model.SimpleAtom.transform(SimpleAtom.java:2)
at androidx.test.espresso.web.model.SimpleAtom.transform(SimpleAtom.java:3)
at androidx.test.espresso.web.action.AtomAction$3.apply(AtomAction.java:1)
at androidx.test.espresso.web.action.AtomAction$3.apply(AtomAction.java:2)
at androidx.test.tools.crawler.obfuscated.bj.d.doTransform(AbstractTransformFuture.java:1)
at androidx.test.tools.crawler.obfuscated.bj.d.doTransform(AbstractTransformFuture.java:2)
at androidx.test.tools.crawler.obfuscated.bj.e.run(AbstractTransformFuture.java:9)
at androidx.test.tools.crawler.obfuscated.bj.g.execute(DirectExecutor.java:1)
at androidx.test.tools.crawler.obfuscated.bj.a.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1)
at androidx.test.tools.crawler.obfuscated.bj.a.complete(AbstractFuture.java:11)
at androidx.test.tools.crawler.obfuscated.bj.a.set(AbstractFuture.java:2)
at androidx.test.tools.crawler.obfuscated.bj.ab.set(SettableFuture.java:1)
at androidx.test.espresso.web.action.AtomAction$1.setResult(AtomAction.java:1)
at androidx.test.espresso.web.action.AtomAction$2.run(AtomAction.java:1)
at androidx.test.tools.crawler.obfuscated.bj.g.execute(DirectExecutor.java:1)
at androidx.test.tools.crawler.obfuscated.bj.a.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1)
at androidx.test.tools.crawler.obfuscated.bj.a.complete(AbstractFuture.java:11)
at androidx.test.tools.crawler.obfuscated.bj.a.set(AbstractFuture.java:2)
at androidx.test.tools.crawler.obfuscated.bj.d.setResult(AbstractTransformFuture.java:1)
at androidx.test.tools.crawler.obfuscated.bj.e.run(AbstractTransformFuture.java:12)
at androidx.test.tools.crawler.obfuscated.bj.g.execute(DirectExecutor.java:1)
at androidx.test.tools.crawler.obfuscated.bj.a.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1)
at androidx.test.tools.crawler.obfuscated.bj.a.complete(AbstractFuture.java:11)
at androidx.test.tools.crawler.obfuscated.bj.a.set(AbstractFuture.java:2)
at androidx.test.espresso.web.action.JavascriptEvaluation$ValueCallbackFuture.onReceiveValue(JavascriptEvaluation.java:1)
at u2.a(PG:1)
at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.a(PG:210)
at Ql.run(Unknown Source:4)
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:336)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:197)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8016)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1076)

Comment: We created a bug for this issue and will follow up after we have more insights. Thanks!

Comment: have you found any solution?